# Disable CakePHP DebugKit

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I recently installed the insanely useful DebugKit plugin for my CakePHP projects and I just realized that something wasn't working the way I expected it to work. I assumed that when I pushed code to production, the DebugKit wouldn't show up because my debug value is `0`.

Although I haven't pushed to production yet, I did have a need to disable the plugin in my dev environment and it seems that simply setting the debug value to `0` isn't enough. I actually had to remove the plugin from my `AppController` to get it to stop...debugging.

Is this expected? There are no specific instructions for disabling, but I made one of those assumption things that setting `Configure::write( 'debug', 0 )` would suffice. Is this a bug or was my expectation just wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Argh. I'm not finding that to be the case. Maybe I have some goofy caching stuff going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely right, in CakePHP 1.2 I do this.

In my **app_controller.php** I use the following.

```
public function constructClasses() {

    if(Configure::read('debug') >= 1):
    $this->components[] = 'DebugKit.Toolbar';
    endif;

    parent::constructClasses();
}
```

Its simple and elegant.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, Tass. From the way the instructions are worded, I guess I just assumed that the debug value was the show/hide key. Stupid me.

Answer (score 0):

just go to core.php file in app/Config

find this line `Configure::write('debug', 2);`

change to `Configure::write('debug', 0);`

Answer (score 0):

In config/app.php
you will see ...

---

**'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),**

---

by default it is set to true, change it to false.
that is..

**'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', false), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),**